# Extract values from a line containing a string in a specific column

Tags: bash

I have an output like this:

```
| Value | Value2 | Name1 | Type | Date | Status |
| Value1 | Value1 | Name1 | Type1 | Date | Success |
| Value2 | Value2 | Name2 | Type1 | Date | Failed |
| Value2 | Value2 | Name3 | Type1 | Date | Pending |
```

I want to get each column values in variables for each line containing status "Pending" in the last column.

Here the matching line would be:

```
| Value2 | Value2 | Name3 | Type1 | Date | Pending |
```

I want to get each column of this line in a variable:

myvar1=Value2
myvar2=Value2
myvar3=Name3
myvar4=Type1
myvar5=Date

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I dont get it. Can you show an output example of the target variables?

Comment: I edited my answer to add more information.

Comment: Please read over the [questions guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Have you considered using `awk`? `awk` is designed for line by line column handling. e.g. `awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" } { if ($7 == " Pending ") {print $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 } }'`

Comment: Whiy not simply `grep Pending` ??

Comment: He searchs about `Pending` only in the last column. Some answers are using grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simply:

```
while IFS= read -r line ;do
    IFS='|' read -r foo myvar{1..6} foo <<<"$line"
    [ "${myvar6}" ] && [ -z "${myvar6//*Pending*}" ] && echo "$line"
done <inputfile ;
```

Will print:

```
| Value2 | Value2 | Name3 | Type1 | Date | Pending |
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can select the line. If it is only one ending with "Pending", this would work:

```
line=$(grep '| Pending |$' file.txt | sed 's/\s*|\s*/|/g' | sed 's/^|//g')
```

The variable `line` now has only the values separeted with the pipe symbol, without the spaces around it and no pipe symbols at the beginning the line.

Then, if you do not use an array, you can manually assign the variables like

```
myvar1=$(echo $line | awk  -F'|' '{print $1}')
myvar2=$(echo $line | awk  -F'|' '{print $2}')
...
```

If there are many lines containing the keyword "Pending" you have to use an array or a dynamic structure instead of static variable names.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the output you mention comes from a command named `your_command`. If you have it in a file, for example, that command could be `cat that_file`.

I think that a switch inside a loop is a legible elegant solution.

```sh
your_command | (
    while read line; do
        case $line in
        *'Pending |')
            IFS='|' read -ra myvar <<< "$line"
            echo ${myvar[1]}
            echo ${myvar[2]}
            echo ${myvar[3]}
            echo ${myvar[4]}
            echo ${myvar[5]}
        ;;
        *)
            echo ...IGNORED $line
        ;;
        esac
    done
)
```

The output with the example you have given is the following

```
...IGNORED | Value | Value2 | Name1 | Type | Date | Status |
...IGNORED | Value1 | Value1 | Name1 | Type1 | Date | Success |
...IGNORED | Value2 | Value2 | Name2 | Type1 | Date | Failed |
Value2
Value2
Name3
Type1
Date
```

If you don't want to use an array, because whatever reason, you can change the `IFS='|' read -ra myvar <<< "$line"` line for

```sh
myvar1=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f 2)
myvar2=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f 3)
myvar3=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f 4)
myvar4=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f 5)
myvar5=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, what you asked for:

```
$: while read -r myvar1 myvar2 myvar3 myvar4 myvar5 Pending
>  do echo "myvar1=[$myvar1] myvar2=[$myvar2] myvar3=[$myvar3] myvar4=[$myvar4] myvar5=[$myvar5]"
>  done < <( sed -n '/[|]\s*Pending\s*[|]\s*$/{ s,[ |], ,g; s/^ //; s/ $//; p; }' file )
myvar1=[Value2] myvar2=[Value2] myvar3=[Name3] myvar4=[Type1] myvar5=[Date]
```

The `sed` selects only the records you want (`/[|]\s*Pending\s*[|]\s*$/`) converts all the delimiter-crap to single spaces (`s,[ |], ,g;`, breaks if you have any spaces embedded in your data), strips leading and trailing delimiters (`s/^ //; s/ $//;`), and prints the result (`-n` says don't print by default, `p;` says do print this records now).

But I think you should seriously reconsider the spaces around your delimiter, unless you wanted to keep them as part of the data. I'd leave off the leading and maybe the trailing delimiter. I'd also really consider putting them into an array, though I do understand you may want to use the fields by name...just don't *call* them `myvar1`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } $(NF-1)~/Pending/ { gsub(/^\s*\|\s*/, "", $0); NF-=2; print $0; }' file.txt | while IFS='|' read myVar1 myVar2 myVar3 myVar4 myVar5
do
    #Do something
done
```